# Biased coin flip with sampled observation (variation)

Tags: probability

Let's say a coin flip has probability $H$ to come out as heads, and $1−H$ to come out as tails. Coin flips are independent to each other. Let's say we flip many times but for each flip we randomly and independently decide if we will look at the result, by a probability of $L$, or $L = 1-B$ ("B" means blind, i.e. not look).

Question: what's the probability of "observing at least one of the first $N$ heads"?

*Note: This question shares the same context as [Biased coin flip with sampled observation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651051/biased-coin-flip-with-sampled-observation), but the actual question is different. In that question, the total amount of coin flips is fixed. In this question, the total amount of coin flips is not fixed, but the number of heads.*

FWIW, I found this question difficult, because it seems I need to add up the probability for all different lengths of the flipping series up to $N$ heads (i.e. length can be from $N$, i.e. all heads, to $inf$, i.e. never heads). I couldn't think of a different way, to model it as a multiplication of probabilities, at least yet.

Comment: Question needs clarification - relationship between L and B.

Comment: I don't understand.  If each head is observed with probability $p$  independently of all the others then the probability that at least one is observed is $1-(1-p)^N$.  What else is there to say?  I have no guess as to what $L,B$ are and $H$ appears to be irrelevant.

Comment: Oh actually you are right, @lulu. Yeah none of the tails matter. lol  Is it that simple? I was overthinking by so much...

Comment: So, using the symbols in the question, the answer is $1 - B^N$.

Comment: As @lulu correctly pointed out in their comment under the question, the answer is $1 - B^N$. The tails are irrelevant to the answer.